# Using vagrant as part of development environment

Tags: python, development-environment, vagrant

I'm investigating ways to add vagrant to my development environment. I do most of  my web development in python, and I'm interested in python-related specifics, however the question is more general.

I like the idea of having all development-related stuff isolated in virtual machine, but I haven't yet discovered an effective way to work with it. Basically, I see 3 ways to set it up:

1. Have all services (such as database server, MQ, etc) as well as an application under development to run in VM. Developer would ssh to VM and edit sources there, run app, tests, etc, all in an ssh terminal.
2. Same as 1), but edit sources on host machine in mapped directory with normal GUI editor. Run application and tests on vagrant via ssh. This seems to be most popular way to use vagrant.
3. Host only external services in VM. Install app dependencies into virtualenv on host machine and run app and tests from there.

All of these approaches have their own flaws:

1. Developing in text console is just too inconvenient, and this is the show-stopper for me. While I'm experienced ViM user and could live with it, I can't recommend this approach to anyone used to work in any graphical IDE.
2. You can develop with your familiar tools, but you cannot use autocompletion, since all python libs are installed in VM. Your tracebacks will point to non-local files. You will not be able to open library sources in your editor, ctags will not work.
3. Losing most of "isolation" feature: you have to install all compilers, *-dev libraries yourself to install python dependencies and run an app. It is pretty easy on linux, but it might be much harder to set them all up on OSX and on Windows it is next to impossible I guess.

**So, the question is**: is there any remedy for problems of 2nd and 3rd approaches? More specifically, how is it possible to create an isolated and easily replicatable environment, and yet enjoy all the comfort of development on host machine?

Comment: I had similar musings. Did you find a good solution? Lately I've been thinking that Docker (or Linux containers, more generally) may provide a better system, but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Personally, I'm using 3rd option from above. All my fellow developers use Ubuntu, so we have a luxury of having pretty similar host machine configurations. So we just can install bunch of ubuntu packages and get away with it. I came to conclusion that you *have* to make those sacrifices in the name of dev environment independence. And it only makes sense to switch to option 1 or 2 when ongoing price of option 3 becomes too high (i.e. you have to support too many dev environment variants). But I still keep an eye on it. If Docker solves at least some of these problems, let me know!

Comment: My problem with #3 is what to do if different projects have conflicting dependencies. Now I realized PyCharm works with Vagrant by allowing remote Python interpreters. Of course, it's Python specific and may tie you to an IDE (I don't know if others support this). With Docker I'm hoping you can have a development environment for each project, complete with GUI editor. Of course you can already do that with other virtualization methods, but at a greater performance cost.

Answer (score 0):

In most IDE you can add "library" path which are outside the project so that your code completion etc works. About the traceback, I'm unfamiliar with python but this sounds like issue that are resolved by "mapping" paths between servers and dev machine. This is generally the reason why #2 is often the way to go (Except when you have a team willing to do #1).

Comment: You can add a library path outside the project, but not inside the virtual machine, unless the folder you share between the Vagrant instance and the host is broader than just the code directory (which you could do, I suppose, I haven't thought about it enough to know whether it's practical).